# Can't find Uploaded folder in php?

Tags: php

I've created two files namely (index.html) and (upload_file.php) in my "var/www/html/nns" folder. Here the codes....

//index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

//upload_file.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 200000) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  } 
?>
```

Finally i've created myown folder namely "upload" in "var/html/nns/". In order to upload an image using index.html then it shows in....

Upload: new_bar.png
Type: image/png
Size: 0.211895 kB
Temp file: /tmp/phpjSn4x8
Stored in: upload/new_bar.png

But i've didn't find any image in my folder... what happens??? am I missing something???

Answer (score 1):

Try using an absolute path to the upload folder rather than a relative one, such as:-

```
$source=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$destination=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$result=@move_uploaded_file($source,$destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have provided the write permissions i.e 777 to your `upload` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dot and a dash in front of the folder name.

```
./upload/
```

If the above solution is not working, try changing the permission of the upload folder.